# $location.path not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on angularjs form where I need to navigate to other template on click on anchor tag. `ng-click` is working but problem is with `$location.path`. 
here is main  template

```
<a href="#" class="forgot-txt" ng-show="loginUser.typeofUser == 'ExternalUser'" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); ShowForgotPasswordForm()">Forgot Password</a>
```

Now on its controller I have mentioned same method name

```
$scope.ShowForgotPasswordForm = function () {
            $location.path("/forgotpasswordform");
        };
```

Now main controllerjs and `forgotpasswordform` form both are in same folder.

Then I added this form to directive js file which is again in same folder.

```
angularFormsApp.directive('forgotpasswordform',
    function () {
        var baseurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: baseurl + 'app/Login/forgotPasswordForm.html'
        }

    });
```

and template for forgot password is as below, which is also in same folder

```
<!--ForgotPassword Form Start-->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <form class="form-signin padding mg-tb200" novalidate name="forgotpasswordform" role="form">
            <h3 class="line-btm">Forgot Password</h3>
            <p class="lh20">
                Please enter a valid email ID in the text field below,
if it matches our database, a password reset link
will be sent on this email ID.
            </p>
            <input type="email" class="form-control log-input" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <button class="btn-submit right" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!--ForgotPassword Form End-->
```

But when I click on anchor tag its going to function `ShowForgotPasswordForm`
but not navigating to form.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location.pathname then, if $location is not undefined it should work.

Comment: I am not getting any error regarding $location... its working.. problem is not showing new template

Comment: @Mahajan344 the problem is that Directives and Paths do not work the way you think they do. If you create a directive named forgotpasswordform and then go to /forgotpasswordform it will not show that directive. You need to use a router. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few problems with your code.

First it looks like you have a conceptual mistake that the directive name is linked with the URL path. This is not the case.

But you can link them using a router such as the Component-Router, uiRouter or ngRouter.

Lets take a look at how this would look using uiRouter:

We add change your link to use the uiRouter state reference directive

```
<a ui-sref="forgotPassword"
   class="forgot-txt" 
   ng-show="loginUser.typeofUser == 'ExternalUser'">
     Forgot Password
</a>
```

We will replace your directive with a controller. I won't include the code here.

Now we will define a state configuration:

```
forgotPasswordStateConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];
function forgotPasswordStateConfig($stateProvider) {

   $stateProvider
       .state('forgotPassword', {
           url: 'forgotpassword',
           templateUrl: 'app/Login/forgotPasswordForm.html',
           controller: 'ForgotPasswordCtrl as ctrl'
       });
}

app.config(forgotPasswordStateConig);
```